# Thunderbird Facebook chat, disable sound

Tags: thunderbird, notifications, facebook, chat

I connected my Facebook account to Thunderbird chat, all nice, but every new chat message i get sound notification, which really annoying.

Can I disable that sound notifications only for chat, but not for email or else?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Option > Advance > Config Editor, search for `mail.chat.play_notification_sound` and change it to False.